# Help with TSQL join query

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, sql-server-2008

Based on below 2 tables

```
declare @t1 table
(
    Id int,
    Title varchar(100),
    RelatedId int
)
insert into @t1 values(1,'A',2)
insert into @t1 values(1,'A',3)

declare @t2 table
(
    Id int,
    Title varchar(100)
)
insert into @t2 values
(2,'B'),
(3,'C')
```

I am trying to get the below output

```
Id    Title     RelatedItems 
---------------------------------
1     A         2 (B), 3 (C)
```

I tried the following:

```
select t1.Id,t1.Title, cast(t2.Id as varchar) + ' (' + t2.Title + ')' from @t1 as t1
left outer join @t2 as t2
on t1.RelatedId=t2.Id
```

But that gives 2 different rows. I want just one row with the data combined in the third column (as shown above). Pls. suggest.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use:

```
SELECT DISTINCT
       b.id,
       b.title,
       STUFF((SELECT ','+ CAST(t2.id AS VARCHAR(100)) + ' ('+ t2.title +')'
                FROM t2
                JOIN t1 a ON a.relatedid = t2.id
               WHERE a.id = b.id
             FOR XML PATH('')), 1, 1, '')
  FROM t1 b
```